# Communication between servlet and jsp doesn't work - PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, servlets

I'm trying to pass information from my servlet to a jsp , where some fields are passed successfully and some aren't .

This is the initial page where I enter the input :

[image]

The code of `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Bank application</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<table class="title">
  <tr><th>Web Bank application</th></tr>
</table>


<br/>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration</legend>
  <form action="register"> 
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    Address   : <input type="text" name="address"><br>
    ID-number : <input type="text" name="idnumber"><br>
    User-Name : <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Password  : <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

And I want to pass the data to a jsp that's called `show-name.jsp` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Thanks for Registering</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="./css/styles.css"
      type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Congratulations ! You are now registered to our bank</h1>
<h2>First Name: ${name.firstName}</h2>  // that's okay 
<h2>Last Name: ${name.lastName}</h2>    // that's okay  
<h2>Address: ${name.address}</h2>       // that's okay 
<h2>Password: ${name.password}</h2>     // that's okay 
<h2>User-Name: ${name.userName}</h2>    // that's not okay 
<h2>Id Number: ${name.idnumber}</h2>    // that's not okay 
</body></html>
```

I get the following Exception in Eclipse :

```
root cause 

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'userName' not found on type model.Person
```

OR :

```
root cause 

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'idnumber' not found on type model.Person
```

What's weird is , that all the other `4` fields are presented great , meaning `name.firstName` & `name.lastName` & `name.address` & `name.password` , but the other two are not , even though that I added a couple of `System.out.prinln`-s :

```
      System.out.println(person.getID());
      System.out.println(person.getUsername());
```

In the servlet , and the data is presented to the `console` successfully , meaning I get :

```
4444
5555
```

. But from some reason the data is partially not passed to the `jsp` .

Why  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because EL uses getters for getting properties of bean.

In your `Person` bean getter for `idnumber` is not `getIdnumber` or `isIdnumber` but `getID` so you can see error that say that property 'idnumber' can't be found on type model.Person.

Same about getter for `userName` it is not `getUserName` but `getUsername`

Answer (score 1):

You shall change your EL to `name.username` or you shall change your `Person` class and rename the method to `getUserName()` (the N in userName in the EL is capitalized but it is not capitalized in your Person class)